# PHP Include file from folder

Tags: php

I apologise in advance, I have googled & stackoverflow'd this and cannot get to the correct answer I need.

I have the following;

```
if ($radiobutton == "1"){

    require ("/test/_testpage1.php");

}
```

radiobutton 2 also doing the same but going to testpage2.php instead. Neither of this is working. But if i move testpage1.php OUT of the /test/ folder it works perfectly fine just in public_html.

```
if ($radiobutton == "1"){

    require ("_testpage1.php");

}
```

The above works fine, but in the interest in keeping things tidy & easier for me to manage I wanted to put things in folders.

PLEASE may somebody support on something I am quite clearly missing?

Comment: remove the first slash in your first example, to get a relative path.. ?!

Comment: My god.. Thank you, I knew it would be something so simple I am missing.

Comment: Rizier123, please.. sorry but i'm noobie in stackoverflow, why you are answer in comments and not in answers? Exist any difference?

Comment: @Oscargeek There are probably already few questions/answers, which explains the difference between relative and absolute paths, which is OP's problem here. (Since I don't have any dupe in my head right now, I didn't searched for it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your html root is /var/www/html (for example) when you try to require('/test/somefile.php') are trying to open in /test/ folder not in /var/www/html/test/

you can try this code?

```
/* without "/" */
require ("test/_testpage1.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more safe to use fullpath than relative path, maybe something like :

```
require 'FULLPATH.DS.testpage2.php'
```

We can debug it more easily rather than relative path